# button below listview in android app

Tags: android

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                              <ListView
                                 android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="195dp"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                                 android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                                 android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                                 android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
                                 android:cacheColorHint="@drawable/white" />
                              </RelativeLayout>
                              <TableLayout 

  android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:gravity="bottom">
  <TableRow
  android:id="@+id/TableRow01">
   <Button
                android:id="@+id/_btn_scannewitem"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"

                android:text="Scan New Item" />
  <Button
                android:id="@+id/_btn_saveNewItem"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"

                android:text="Save Your Item"
                android:visibility="gone" />
   <Button
                android:id="@+id/_btn_changeprofile"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"

                android:text="Change Profile" />
  </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
```

Above is the code i have used for displaying the listview and button but it does not suits for this design i have mentioned

Am working in android app,in that i want to have a button at the bottom of the page.
    i need the  listview  to show whatever items available in the list ,it shows only two items.
    i want like the image i have mentioned below.

[image: i need design like this]

Comment: i don't see any button in your layout code and do you want it below the list view showing all listview items or below on top of the list view in the image you said they are using a frame layout and btns are on top of litview with gravity set as bottom

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a Relative layout and closing it and then you are starting a table layout,that's wrong.Your table layout should be inside the root that is Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
 <TableLayout >

   </TableLayout >                           
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a main parent container layout containing  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" whose scope ends only at the end

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/asda"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/_lv_labels"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="318dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/asda"
    android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_scannewitem"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Scan New Item" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_saveNewItem"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Save Your Item"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/_btn_changeprofile"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="Change Profile" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry i have used code which you have posted here but it dint work for me please suggest some other solution.

Comment: try using it now the relative layouts ending was not shown in code

Comment: Sorry it is not working now also my list view is not showing all the items available in the list.

Comment: can you post screen shot whats the exact problem

Comment: i have posted it now what i am expecting can u please check and suggest me the solution

Comment: the list view is scrolable just check when scrolling all data comes up if so increase the hight of the lv